# Old Scifi novel where the earth is covered in jungle miles thick and the planet has become sentient

Tags: fantasy-genre

I read this novel back in the 80s, all I really remember was that it is set in the earth's very very distant future. The earth is covered with jungles and organic ooze many miles thick and it seems that it has become sentient. The mother Earth has found some sort of stasis pod with a female human that she awakens and takes care of. The female becomes lonely so the mother earth finds another pod with a man it in. But I do believe the man dies, swallowed up by the jungle.